# Uncaught ReferenceError: mountNode is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

forgive me i've searched everywhere and I'm new in reactjs and trying out examples. I have an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mountNode is not defined
```

I am following the example from here http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

and my code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/reactjs/react.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/reactjs/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script src="/javascripts/reactjs/build/helloworld.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
    /** @jsx React.DOM */

    var UserGist = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          username: '',
          lastGistUrl: ''
        };
      },

      componentDidMount: function() {
        $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
          var lastGist = result[0];
          this.setState({
            username: lastGist.owner.login,
            lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
          });
        }.bind(this));
      },

      render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.username}last gist is
            <a href={this.state.lastGistUrl}>here</a>.
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    React.renderComponent( <UserGist source="https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists" />, mountNode );


    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to tell React where to mount the `<UserGist />` component. You probably want to replace `mountNode` with `document.getElementById('example')` to refer to your `<div id="example"></div>` element:

```
React.render(
  <UserGist source="https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists" />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Comment: When trying this I got `React.renderComponent is not a function` however I found that if I did `React.render` instead I got the result I was hoping for thanks!

Comment: @ak85 Yes, we renamed the API. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Being the accepted answer done, I'd like to add one thing: Don't forget to include references to all necessaries js's libs in your html head section if you are testing this out of "kit examples folder"

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```