# React Js: mountNode is not defined no-undef error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newly learning the React Js. I found the example at this  [Link](https://reactjs.org/). But when I tried the first code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello {this.props.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloMessage name="Taylor" />,
  mountNode
);
export default HelloMessage;
```

I am getting this error

> ./src/App.js   Line 18:  'mountNode' is not defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

I have already seen the answer at this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600443/uncaught-referenceerror-mountnode-is-not-defined). But I'm sorry I couldn't get what is explained there. Provide me the suggestions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Even If I keep the <div id="app"> and at the ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloMessage name="Taylor" />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);   
Its giving me the error Target container is not a DOM element.

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well

Comment: @BharathRao As Klugjo in his answer stated you need to define mountNode, but whatever id that you are using for mountNode must be present in your HTML element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ReactDOM.render() method is already located under

> src/index.js

like:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

The above code renders over component in the root div located in the `public/index.html`

> src/App.js

**--->initially** it looked like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Finally -->** Now instead of rendering the App Component...we can either write the HelloMessage component under the same file or replace the App Component with something like this..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
        Hello {this.props.name}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After that I'm able to see the **Hello** Message in the browser `localhost:3000`. But the Name Taylor is not displayed there...So what I did is passed the name props from the `index.js` file something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
//Passed the name props to the
ReactDOM.render(<App name = "Taylor"/>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Now After this point I got the successful output **Hello Taylor**. If you are replacing the App component with HelloMessage component, don't forget to import that file in the `index.js`

Answer (score 4):

The error message you are getting is a linting error. (static code analysis)

Make sure your `mountNode` variable exists.

or use something like:

```
render(<HelloMessage />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Also make sure that you have a DOM element with id `app` in your HTML code:

for example:

```
<div id="app" />
```

Comment: When I use this:
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="app"/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloMessage/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
I'm getting this error:
Target is not a DOM container
ReactDOM.render(
  15 |   <HelloMessage/>,
  16 |   document.getElementById('app')
  17 | );

Comment: `class HelloMessage extends React.Component { render() { return ( <div id="app"/> ); } } ` does not sound correct. Can you update your post instead with the HTML + the full react code ?

Comment: mountNode could simply be a div tag but it must exist. This is usually a element that should pre-exist in your HTML. Certain playgrounds like JSComplete have this predefined for you to try. I would try your code in JScomplete.com/playground. This should work fine there because they already have all the libraries setup there. You should be able to inspect there and see what mountNode looks like.